# 1 Laravel Installation with 2 TLDs

Tags: laravel

I'm allowing my customers to upload large files. Because I'm using Cloudflare, anything over 100 MB gets rejected, which is no good.

So what I'm thinking of doing is switching the upload form action from `mysite.com/upload` to `mysite.net/upload`. This way I'm using a domain name that isn't going through Cloudflare, so file sizes won't be restricted.

I've set up `mysite.net` as a site in Forge to mirror `mysite.com` by setting the root location in nginx to point to the current folder of `mysite.com`. So now when someone goes to `mysite.net` they see the contents of `mysite.com`.

Unfortunately, `mysite.net` is now open to DDOS attacks because it isn't running through Cloudflare.

So what I'd *like* to do is make it so that `mysite.net/upload` is the only route that's open under that domain, and that it's only accessible from my load balanced servers.

Is this possible, and if so: how do I do it?

I've been researching this and haven't really come across an answer that applies to me, the most common scenario is using subdomains, which is not applicable in my situation.

Comment: Would you be open to rethinking your upload setup? For example, using chunked uploads would sidestep the 100MB limitation, and allow better control over upload errors and network issues. [Here's an example implementation](https://hackernoon.com/resumable-file-upload-in-php-handle-large-file-uploads-in-an-elegant-way-e6c6dfdeaedb).

Comment: I would be but I'm using a package to handle file uploads and it's too ingrained into the app to change it now. I thought it already chunked files, but I'm guessing not... I reached out to them for confirmation,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out; I decided to use a subdomain as it was easier.

I went into Cloudflare, added the subdomain `upload.example.com` (of course, use your real domain) so traffic could hit it, and then turned off protection for the subdomain so that large files could be uploaded.

I updated my `.env` file and added the `SESSION_DOMAIN` variable, so that the user's session will work across both `example.com` and `upload.example.com` domains.

```
SESSION_DOMAIN=".example.com"
```

Notice that the domain starts with a period, and the value is enclosed in quotes. If you omit the quotes your users will not be able to login to your app, and if you use Envoyer omitting quotes will break the decryption when editing your `.env` file.

I then added a new group to my routes file to handle traffic to the subdomain. I added a route to redirect all `GET` traffic back to the original site (`https://example.com`), and added a `POST` route to handle the uploads.

```
Route::group(['domain' => 'upload.example.com'], function () {
    Route::get('/', function () {
        return redirect(url('https://example.com'));
    });

    Route::post('upload', 'UploadController@store')->middleware('throttle:4,1');
});
```

And then in my form...

```
<form action="https://upload.example.com/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Finally, I cleared my browser's cache and cookies, then logged into the site and uploaded a large file! :)